# Grab mode: constraint movement to an axis of a custom coordinate space WITHOUT the gizmo?

Tags: interface, constraints

Up untill recently I thought you can only constraint grab mode to a global axis, but now I know that double tapping a needed axes will constraint the movement to that axis in the normal coordinate space, now my question is is there a way to do the same for a custom coorditante space (the one you can set up thought the "N" menu)?

Now I know how to do it with the gizmo: you just switch to the coordinate space you have created and use the gizmo, but is there a way to do it with the gizmo switched off (a hotkey/a command that can be made into a hotkey)?

Comment: I think you can double press the corresponding axis letters, `X` `X` `Z`,  to constraint to the secondary/local axis while translating. Repeated tapping will toggle between available axis (also works during other transform operator)

Comment: It only sycles local/global man :sad:

Comment: Do you have an active transform orientation other than the default world set in tge 3D view toolshelf? It should
cycle through global >custom if you do

Comment: omg... it actually does... I simply never had a space set up... I am so dumb... ) thanks!